# Python Code for Triangles

Tags: python

I have this task to do :Write a procedure called triangle that takes in a number and then prints out a triangle of
that height.Like this:

```
      *
     ***
    *****
   *******
```

The only solution I found was this code :

```
def triangle(size):
    spaces=""
    stars=""
    line=""
    for i in range(0,size):
        for j in range(0,(size-1-i)+11-(size-1-i)-i): 
            line=line+" "

        for k in range(0,2*i+1):
            line=line+"*"

        print(line)
        line=""

    triangle(2)
    triangle(3)
    triangle(4)
```

I just want to know does anyone have a simpler way of doing this or a way to simplify this code and making it more readable?

Comment: What's wrong with this? This code pretty much simple and readable to me...and self explanatory as well.

Comment: i understand the Structure , But I don't understand how the person worked out the calculations to form the triangle e.g line 6

Comment: Don't try to understand the calculus of line 6, as it is bugged. Try calling triangle(15) for example.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a one-liner that will probably prove your teacher you copied from internet:

**Edited** following OP edit:

```
def triangle(n) : print('\n'.join(map(lambda i:('{:^'+str(2*n)+'}').format('*'*(2*i+1)), range(n))))
```

Comment: And here is my funnier one-liner : `def triangle(n) : print('\n'.join(map(lambda i:'*'*(2*i+1), range(n))))`

Comment: And here is a centered triangle: `def triangle(n) : print('\n'.join(map(lambda i:('{:^'+str(2*n)+'}').format('*'*(2*i+1)), range(n))))`

Comment: Can you replace the answer as it currently stands with your last comment here? As it is, it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: OP reformatted the question. I've edited my answer to give the correct answer. :)

Comment: @DainDwarf When I run it it Gives me an empty line , can you please write it out in the way you would on pythonscriptor.

Comment: I don't know pythonscriptor.

Comment: Doesn't matter , I meant any python coding software , Its just I use that one.

Comment: It works fine on my ipython. Did you *call* the function after defining it?

Comment: Idiot me sorry. ;) and Thanks p.s. Can you explain line 6 for me please I don't know how the person done the calculations.

Answer (score 2):

As you're using Python 3, you have some nice options with the `print()` function:

```
def triangle(size):
    print(*(('{:^'+str(2*size+1)+'}').format('*'*row) for row in range(1, 2*size+1, 2)), sep='\n')
```

This creates a formatted string that centers the proper number of stars for each row, and then sends each row as an argument to `print()`, with a newline as a separator.

```
>>> triangle(4)
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
>>> triangle(5)
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def triangle(line):
    for numberofsymbol in range(line):
        for j in range(line-numberofsymbol): print(" ", end='')
        for j in range(numberofsymbol): print("* ", end='')
        print("")

triangle(10)


OUPUT:
         * 
        * * 
       * * * 
      * * * * 
     * * * * * 
    * * * * * * 
   * * * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * * 
 * * * * * * * * *
```